# How to determine what process controls key combinations?

Tags: keyboard

I'd like to determine which process is handling a particular key combination. I've looked through the System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts list. I've also looked through another utility (Alfred) I use and cannot find the key combo in question listed.

Anyone know of a tool that will show which processes are registered as global hotkey handlers?

Comment: Several menu bar apps have the ability to launch or activate using a global hotkey. What does the global hotkey in question do if I may ask?

Comment: It's currently bringing up an app called Dash. I checked Dash's options though and no global hotkey is set.

Comment: If it's the same app in the App Store (the documentation snippets app), did you try looking at Preferences > General > Global Search Shortcut?